# gmtime function free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, free

when i test gmtime function an error happen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    struct timeval *tv = (struct timeval *)malloc(sizeof(struct timeval));
    struct timezone *tz = NULL;
    struct tm *aTm = (struct tm *)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));

    int r = 0;

    r = gettimeofday(tv, tz);
    if (r == -1) {
        printf("gettimeofday error");
        return 1;
    }

    aTm = gmtime(&tv->tv_sec);

    printf("%s", ctime(&tv->tv_sec));
    printf("%d\n", (int)time(&tv->tv_sec));

    printf("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", (Tm->tm_year+1900), (Tm->tm_mon+1), Tm->tm_mday, Tm->tm_hour, Tm->tm_min, Tm->tm_sec);

    free(tv);
    printf("%p\n", aTm);
    free(aTm); //there is an error

    return 0;
}
```

my mechine:

```
Linux jim 3.13.0-62-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:29:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

gcc version:

```
gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
```

the error:

```
*** Error in `./a': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f1dfe9b4de0 ***
segmentation fault
```

gdb message:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a 
0x7ffff7dd8de0
*** Error in `/tmp/a': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffff7dd8de0 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a4bcc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory
```

I don't change aTm argument to static values, when I free it, an error happen.

who can help me.

Answer (score 3):

```
aTm = gmtime(&tv->tv_sec);
...
free(aTm); //there is an erro
```

You can only pass to `free` what you got from `malloc`, not the pointer returned from `gmtime`!

You probably wanted:

```
memcpy (aTm, gmtime (&tv->tv_sec), sizeof (struct tm));
```

Or just:

```
*aTm = * gmtime(&tv->tv_sec);
```

This copies the return from `gmtime` into the existing buffer, rather than changing the pointer to point to the library's buffer.

Comment: Also, that assignment to `aTm` overwrites the pointer returned by `malloc` earlier, causing a memory leak.

Comment: I test. yes, you are right. when i print the aTm(%p), the values are diffrent.Thanks! David Schwartz melpomene